# Manipulating a class list in a loop, while the condition iterates over that list

Tags: java, arrays, class, arraylist

Sorry if the title was unclear. I'm not exactly sure how to word it.

So I have static Game class. This Game class contains multiple ArrayLists as class variables.

My job is to reduce the Game as much as possible. To do this I have implemented a reduce(Game) function which performs the next reduction step.

Of course, the reduce function edits the array lists stored under the Game class. For example, it will remove turns that are not needed.

I have a reducable(Game) function that returns true if the game can be reduced more. The function iterates over the various moves and returns true if a move is not needed, false otherwise.

The problem I am having, is that the reducable function is attempting to use/lookup moves that were deleted prior in the iterations.

So for example if I try:

```
while(reducable(game))
     reduce(game);
```

I get an array index out of bounds error from reducable, because it is using the original array size and not the new size.

If I depend on something such as input or a counter then it works fine

```
while(!scanner.nextLine().contains("stop"))
     reduce(game);
```

However this is not a reasonable solution because I am trying to make it perform automatic and I will not know how many reductions are needed.

Here is the base of my code being used

```
public static void performReduction(Game game){
    int i = 0;
    while(reducable(game)){
        reduce(game);
    }

}
public static boolean reducable(Game game){
    for(int i = 0; i < game.turns.get(0).size(); i++){
        for(int j = 0; j < game.turns.get(1).size(); j++){
            if(notNeeded(....))
                return true;
        }
    }
    return false;
}
public static boolean notNeeded(Game g, int p){
        for(int i = 0; i < game.turns.get(p).size(); i++){
            for(int j = 0; j < game.turns.get(p).size(); j++){
                 if(....)
                    return truel
                }
            }
        return false;
}
```

The problem, more or less:
The reduce function removes information from the lists in Game. (ie. turns)
The conditional function that performs the while loop needs to iterate over these functions to determining if a reduction is possible.
Gives an out of bounds error for attempting to access list indices that are no longer there.

I've tried using the reducable function as a class function, but that gave the same results. I've also tried having reduce return a Game instance, and using recursion but that also gave the same results.

`

Comment: Have you tried adding a condition, before executing the content of the `reducable ( ... )` method, like `if ( game.turns.size () > 1 )` only then go with the rest of the flow, else don't go for it!!!! Since the code is not checking for this thingy, it seems that is what is causing `ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException`. In the absence of `reduce ( ... )` method, that is the best thingy it seems to me ::-)

Comment: @nIcEcOw the problem is that there is no designated size that would cause it to stop. The only way it will know when to stop is by running the helper functions with the lists. Which gives the error

Comment: The use of hardcoded values `get ( 0 )/get ( 1 )` is actually raising my eyebrows :-)  and this function is not removing anythingy as yet, so, might be if again a call to this function comes, since no checking is done, it can raise the said exception

Comment: For this purpose It's only a 2 player game. But other functions may use more players

Comment: I don't see anything fundamentally wrong with your approach.  My guess is that `reduce` has a bug.  Maybe it's not adjusting all the information it needs to adjust.  But without seeing it, and seeing `Game`, it's impossible to tell.

Comment: Can you show code of `reduce()` ?